# Magento2: update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure!

Tags: magento2

I have some issue with cron:

```
[2018-08-08 09:19:02] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:    /home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/.htaccess [] []
[2018-08-08 09:20:02] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:    /home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/.htaccess [] []
[2018-08-08 09:21:03] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:    /home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/.htaccess [] []
[2018-08-08 09:22:03] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:    /home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/.htaccess [] []
[2018-08-08 09:23:02] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:    /home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/.htaccess [] []
[2018-08-08 09:24:03] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:    /home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/.htaccess [] []
[2018-08-08 09:25:02] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:    /home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/.htaccess [] []
[2018-08-08 09:26:02] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:    /home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/.htaccess [] []
[2018-08-08 09:27:02] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:    /home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/.htaccess [] []
[2018-08-08 09:28:02] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:    /home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/.htaccess [] []
[2018-08-08 09:29:02] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:    /home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/.htaccess [] []
```

Can anyone suggest how to solve it?